# Yii2 Rest URL Routing

Tags: php, rest, yii, yii2

I have a problem calling the url of my rest api in Yii2. I want to call a url like:

http://localhost/index-dev.php/myapi/collection/18

where 18 is the Id.

In my web.php config, I have the following code, with other settings from another programmers :

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => true,
        'rules' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['coding/nodes', 'coding/scales','myapi/collection']],                
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        ],            
    ],
```

when i call my URL, i get

Not Found (#404)

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the plural of your model class name in the URL for accessing a single model:

http://localhost/index-dev.php/myapi/collections/18

Take a look at the [documentation of yii\rest\UrlRule](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-urlrule.html):

> The above code will create a whole set of URL rules supporting the following RESTful API endpoints:
>
> - 'PUT,PATCH users/<id>' => 'user/update': update a user
> - 'DELETE users/<id>' => 'user/delete': delete a user
> - 'GET,HEAD users/<id>' => 'user/view': return the details/overview/options of a user
> - 'POST users' => 'user/create': create a new user
> - 'GET,HEAD users' => 'user/index': return a list/overview/options of users
> - 'users/<id>' => 'user/options': process all unhandled verbs of a user
> - 'users' => 'user/options': process all unhandled verbs of user collection

Comment: sorry, this parse error is just from copy&paste the code here, not in the code.
but it is not working anyway.

Comment: OK, but then the error needs to be elsewhere as your code works fine. Is URL rewriting enabled in your vhost or .htaccess?

Comment: yes, it's enabled cause i get the error from yii2, not from the browser.
second i can call "http://localhost/index-dev.php/myapi/collection" this will call the indexAction

Comment: You're right. I might have found the solution and have improved my answer.

Comment: i did not found this anywhere, now it works when i call the url as plural :)
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, you can disable the prural

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => true,
    'rules' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['coding/nodes', 'coding/scales','myapi/collection']],                
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        'pluralize' => false,
    ],            
],
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but i prefer not to change so much in the old code, cause i am developing new features, and should let the old code working. But your solution is also good to know ;)

Answer (score 3):

i suggest create separate module for API
and configure your UrlManager like...:)

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                    'pluralize'=>false,
                    'controller' => ['v1/country','v1/user'],
                    'tokens' => [
                        '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
                    ],
                    'extraPatterns' => [
                        'POST register' => 'register', //from url 
                        'GET exists'=>'exists',
                        'POST login'=>'login',
                        'POST follow'=>'follow',
                        'POST category'=>'category',
                        'PUT profile'=>'profile',
                        'PUT change_password'=>'change_password',
                        'PUT feed_interested'=>'feed_interested',
                    ],


                ]
            ],        
        ]
```

More detail @ [Create Rest Api](http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/)